# Question on implementing Listeners in Android

Tags: java, android, view, android-activity, listener

In Android, is it better to implement Listeners in your Activity, or to individually set Listeners for each View?

For example:

```
public class NewActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
public void onClick(View v) {
}
```

or

```
btnView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener({...});
```

Comment: Specifically for OnClickListener, I'd use `android:onClick` in your layout.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't much of a difference. The advantage to an anonymous class is that the implementation is not callable by anyone with a reference
to your object. The downside is that you end up with a
bunch of extra classes. You can choose which you feel better suits your needs.

Answer (score 0):

There is no performance difference so choose whatever makes your code easier to read